# What's your Django 1.3 tutorial recommendation?

Tags: python, django

Other than the [Django docs tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/), what are recommendations for good Django 1.3 tutorials?

The resources listed in the [Django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials) all seem pretty outdated.

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130061/book-and-tutorial-recommedations-for-django-1-0 but I'm looking specifically for updated Django 1.3 guides.

Thanks.

Comment: actually, the one you want is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/ (the one you linked to is the 'dev' branch)

Comment: The Django Book (http://www.djangobook.com/) might still be a good option, although it was originally created for 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Having searched on a regular basis, I can say that there simply aren't any very new books on Django being sold at the major retailers.  And there have been some significant changes to the code since 1.1.

Your best bet is just to continue using the django docs.  The docs for Django are some of the best and most complete on the web.  They do an excellent job of keeping them up to date.

There are tutorials out there on the web for using django in specific ways that aren't covered well on the djangoproject.com site. But they tend to cover only one small area such as how to use django with aptana.  Very useful, but far from complete without many other resources.

And of course, if you get stuck, there is IRC and StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably been to *some* page on the official snippets site, and I agree, it is disappointing to click on a "top user" only to see that they haven't posted anything in years. However, the following is a link to just the entries tagged for 1.3, and depending on how old you thought the snippets in general were, you may find some interesting and relevant information by looking at the circa 1.2 entries as well:

http://djangosnippets.org/search/advanced/?q=+&language=&django_version=1.3

If < 3 months old is more your preference,

http://djangosnippets.org/popular/rated/?page=1&months=3